# Error setting up Jenkins for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, keychain

I'm following the setup described in this 3-parts [tutorial](http://blog.zymr.com/jenkins-integration-with-ios-1). I'm currently testing the build step and receiving the following error message

> Will not set default: file
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain does not exist
>   security: SecKeychainSetDomainDefault user: write permissions error
>   [MyProject iOS] $ /usr/bin/security unlock-keychain -p ***********
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain security:
>   SecKeychainUnlock
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain: The specified
>   keychain could not be found. FATAL: Unable to unlock the keychain.

Now this is  the Jenkins configuration (Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Xcode builder) I'm following:

[image]

Clearly Jenkins is looking for the keychain in the wrong directory. I tried to copy certificates and developer profiles in the System chain but still it cannot find them. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the Keychain path setting that is in the configuration for the build itself.  More specifically:

```
Jenkins ->  <your-build> -> Configure
```

Under **Code signing & OS X keychain options** click on unlock keychain and check the keychain path and see if that is correct.